# What was the first keyboard to have browser forward/back keys?

Tags: keyboards

I know they have been around for a long time, for example this [2003 commit](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-proto-x11proto/commit/f2001f5bd5316842106a98b23f09400688575fa3#diff-b35d21e918c756b86da78959d6bc4a27R61) has support for them. What was the first...?

Comment: You might want to narrow this question down - so far this may result in an argument about what are special function keys and how they are implemented. After all, neither a browser or forward or back are anything new to the 1970s or even before. Keyboards with application specific function keys have always been around. Take the NEOPOST PC Keyboard - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5g5uY63Pq4 - (Got one as well).

Comment: My Thinkpad X30 had them in 2002, but the X20 range didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web didn’t exist back then, but some of IBM’s [3270 terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3270) keyboards had forward and back keys; for example the keyboard provided with the 3279 terminal in 1979 (look at the cursor keys in the bottom right-hand corner):

[image: Photo of an IBM 3279 terminal]

(Photograph by Dave Fischer; [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IBM-3279.jpg); [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).)

Comment: Boom. Sunk it :))

Comment: Definitive proof that "PC Power" came before "Power PC" at IBM ;)